# Gcode parsing problems? - for loop bytes and stings

Tags: python

I am learning python and I need to parse some gcode from a socket, and pass on commands to a serial port.    I have some of it working, using selectors.
conn is my tcp connection that is receiving Gcode.   sbus is my serial port.

Lets say data = b'G0 X1.0 Y2.0 Z0.0 ; move to X,Y,Z'
which is a typical gcode line.
The output of my code below is this:

```
1 b'G0
2 X1.0
3 Y2.0
4 Z0.0
```

So, it discarded everything after the comment like I wanted.
It discarded the naked b'\n' like I wanted.
BUT, that first element includes the b' , and the others do not.
I am confused as to how I should get rid of the b'

I'm sure I am not doing this the right pythonic way, and I was hoping for some insight into how to deal with the b' on the first item (and the last item has a trailing ' if there was no gcode comment, which I'll also have to deal with)

Thanks

```
def read(conn, mask):
    data = conn.recv(1000)  # Should be ready
    print(Color.Red, data,Color.end)  #debug print, make text red
    if data==b'\n':  # don't process the slash-n
        return
    if data:
        conn.send(b'ok\r\n')  # sends back to openPnP
        print('wroteback ok to tcp')  # debug print
        i=1
        for word in repr(data).split(' '):
            if word==';':
                break
            if word=='':
                continue
            print(i,Color.Green+word+Color.end)  # prints each part of gcode line
            i=i+1
        sbus.write(data)  # will actually send translated commands to serial prot, not just echo the data
    else:
        print('closing', conn)
        sel.unregister(conn)
        conn.close()
```

Comment: BTW bravo for knowing how to ask a beautiful question. You have code example and clear request.

Comment: Okay,  I Fixed it how Serge suggested, and that got me moving forward.   Now after messing with re.search I'm able to parse the few Gcode commands needed to get my PnP machine moving.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

b is for bytes. It just tells you that the data type is bytes. Here is a code to examine bytes and string and how to move from one to another.

```
b = b'I am a bytes'
s = 'I am a string'



print(type(b), # bytes
      type(s), # string
      type(b.decode('utf8')), # string
      type(s.encode('utf8')) # bytes
      )

# change byte to string
b_s = b.decode('utf8')
print(b_s == 'I am a bytes')
# True

# change string to bytes
s_b = s.encode('utf8')
print(s_b == b'I am a string')
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
for word in repr(data).split(' ')
```

Data is a byte string, and its representation in Python3 is not an equivalent (unicode) string but that string **enclosed in `b''` or `b""`**. The last `'` is ignored because it comes after the terminal `;`, but the initial `b'` remains.

The correct way is to properly convert the byte string to a unicode one with `decode`:

```
for word in data.decode().split(' ')
```

You can use `data.decode('ascii')` if you want an exception to be raised if the string contains a non ascii character, or `data.decode('ascii', 'ignore')` if you want to ignore any non ascii.

What to remember from that: beware of byte/unicode string conversions

Comment: I was able to fix it the way you suggested here, but when I moved forward to the next step I discovered re, and after learning how that works and how to use it this for loop was made redundant.    x=re.search("(x)([-0-9.]+),data,re.I)  does all the gritty work to extract the X and it's value,  similar lines work for all the gcode.